# Add Storybook to Angular v10 Project

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm working in an Angular v10 project. I cannot update the angular version of this project, as it's used as a dependency to other apps (and therefore needs to maintain the stable version).

I need to add Storybook to this application. I followed the instructions here: https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/install, but I'm getting compiling issues when I try to run `npm run storybook`. `npx sb init` seems to install storybook at v6.4.

As a test, I tried creating a quick angular project (`ng new`) at version 12, and then using `npx sb init` to add storybook. That command also installs storybook at version 6.4 in Angular v12 apps. I get no issues when running `npm run storybook` in the Angular v12 app.
This makes me think that storybook v6.4 isn't compatible with Angular v10. I've tried storybook doesn't seem to list which versions of Angular are compatible with which versions of storybook.

What version of storybook should I be using? Is there a better way to add storybook to Angular v10 project than using `npx sb init`?

You can replicate this by creating a v10 Angular project (set the local @angular/cli to v10, then use `ng new`). And then add story book with `npx sb init`. You'll get the below errors.
[image]

Comment: Can you post the error you get while trying to install SB ? It may be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that, but this is easily replicated. Make a new v10 angular project (set the local @angular/cli to v10, then use `ng new`). And then add story book `npx sb init`. You get the errors

Comment: it seems like dependency issue. why don't you install v5.3.19 instead? it was out 2 years ago right around time angular v10.

Comment: I thought of that too, but the problem seems to be that `npx sb init` sets it up for v6.4. Using that init command, and then setting the storybook pkgs to be at a lower version (v5) and reinstalling causes compiling issues with the storybook files themselves. Right now, I'm trying to install storybook without the init command altogether, but I can't find much help. All the articles I find uses the init command, and storybook's documentation on older versions isn't great. In fact, you can't even see docs for versions past 6.

Answer (score 3):

So I think I've found a solution. After googling `storybook ERROR TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.`, I found a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70412695/7592083) on that error.

TLDR; update your typescript version to latest in devdeps of your project, and run storybook again.

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@latest
npm run storybook
```

It worked for me, so it should for you. Good luck :)

Comment: My typescript is at 4.0.8. I can't update my typescript without it causing issues with my Angular compiler. If I try to update typescript to a higher version, I get `ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.9.2 and <4.1.0 but 4.5.5 was found instead.` when I try to compile the app.

Comment: Weird, it worked fine on my machine. I've checked and my `@angular/compiler` is `10.2.5`. Do you have the same ?

Comment: Yes, I have @angular/compiler-cli@10.2.5. Let me be clear. If I update typescript to the latest, and then run storybook, it compiles. :)
But if I try to serve my app (`ng serve`) I get the error stated in my previous comment. :(

Comment: Aaw shit, I can see a workaround like a "prestorybook" script which change typescript version, it'll work but honnestly I think this is not a good solution. I'm sorry but I'm running out of idea, maybe try to contact storybook support ? Or this can be a good argument to update your angular project to latest version :p

Comment: That preinstall idea might be a good solution (if I'm still forced to be on v10). I've been wanting to update since v11 came out, but they're super concerned about compatibility, even after I show them that the update has no functional changes to our app.
Either way, I appreciate your insight. If I get that preinstall script working, I'll post it to this answer and then accept since it does what I asked.

Comment: Great, I'm looking forward to it :)