# Cannot find 'LeftSegment' & Cannot find 'infer' error in react-router folder in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to upgrade my app from **react-router v3 to v6** actually I installed react-router-dom v6.2.1 and also the react-router v6.2, I am using Typescript so I installed @types as well. @types/react-router v5.1.18 and @types/react-router-dom v5.3.3 with typescript v3.8.

I am getting these two errors,

> Cannot find 'LeftSegment' in node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts
>
> Cannot find 'infer' in node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts

Comment: I've yet to see RRDv6 type definitions in [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom). Looks like v5.3.3 ***is*** the latest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your typescript version:

```
npm i --save-dev typescript@latest
```

Solution by @dolig on [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70854811/add-storybook-to-angular-v10-project).

Comment: It helped actually its working now after upgrading the typescript thanks a lot.  

Got dependency issues with other lib but solved them.